# JSSOR Carousel - How to disable bounce

Tags: carousel, jssor

JSSOR Carousel - How to disable bounce when it gets dragged - Consider there is a single image in carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Set `$DragOrientation` option value to 0 will disable drag.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var options = {
            ...,
            $DragOrientation: 0
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    });
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html